# How to make django login_required decorator raise HTTP401 exception

Tags: python, django

I use Django login_required decorator, but i want `login_required` to raise HTTP401 Unauthorized exception instead of redirecting to login url.

Comment: user_passes_test decorator returns a 500 error. Maybe a lit bit better. Try to explore the LoginRequired mixin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want specifically `login_required` to do it, you might have to override it. Else, you can do this simple thing:

```
def view_func(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
    # write all the code for your view that was there before
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems that only override `login_required` can solve my question. your solution works correctly, but it isn't beautiful like decorator.

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom decorator to return a 401 response if the user is not authenticated.

```py
from functools import wraps
from django.http import HttpResponse

def user_passes_test(test_func):
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request.user):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator

def login_required_401(function=None):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated,
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

**Example**

```py
@login_required_401
def example_view(request):
    # write your code here
```